# Erorr: loading from non-aligned word in MIPS

Tags: mips, memory-address

Any ideas why I'm getting an alignment error? The error in line 7 `lw $t0, 0($t2)` 
"Address Error: loading from non-aligned word [line 7]: 2"
this is my code:

```
sll $t0, $s0, 2     
add $t0, $s6, $t0    
sll $t1, $s1, 2         
add $t1, $s7, $t1    
lw $s0, 0($t0)  
addi $t2, $t0, 4
lw $t0, 0($t2)
add $t0, $t0, $s0 
sw $t0, 0($t1)
```

Comment: The `lw` instruction requires that the address `0($t2)` be a multiple of 4.

Comment: Yes, but if the `lw` on line 5 succeeded, then `0($t2)` must be a multiple of 4.  Right?

Comment: The result of an `lw` is delayed by one cycle.  Thus, `$t0` is not going to be ready in time for the `add` instruction.

Comment: @TimRoberts || after multiple of 4 in line 7, another error moved to line 5 ```lw $s0, 0($t0)  ```

Comment: Well, it's up to you to make sure that `$t0` is a multiple of 4.  It will be after line 1, but if `$s6` is not a multiple of 4, then it won't work.

Comment: If you want more help than an explanation of the error message, then provide more information.  Your post shows no `.data`; it does not describe how `$s0`, `$s6`, or `$s7` get their values; and, the error message you conveyed is incomplete: there should be two addresses associated with this exception: the instruction address and the faulting data access address.